# Converting proc freq output into a dataset

Tags: sas, dataset

I have a sas data set with 564 variables. I need to create a new table with three columns, column1 will be the variables name , column2 will be the value of that variable, and column3 will be observation number.
So if I have a variable gender then gender will be listed 2 times in the variable column, and the gender values will be listed as m in the first row and female in the second row, and the column3 will be just the number of the observation. This is how it should look. Many thanks in advance.

```
var    value obs
gender m      1
gender f      2
ans    yes    3
ans    no     4
```

Comment: In the future, this sort of question is better asked by providing sample data and the code you're using to run frequencies on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to getting a table out of `PROC FREQ` that has all the values in one column is `ods output` combined with `coalescec`.

`ODS OUTPUT` lets you tell `PROC FREQ` to put everything into one dataset (as opposed to `out=` which just puts one Freq table into one dataset).  That gives you a slightly messy result, which we then use `coalescec` to fix.  That function takes a list of variables and returns the first nonmissing value from them; since the `F_` variables always have just one value populated (the formatted value of the variable in the table), it's easy to use them.

```
ods output onewayfreqs=freqs;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
  tables age sex;
run;
ods output close;  *technically unneeded but makes it more clear;

data want;
  set freqs;
  value = left(coalescec(of f_:));
run;
```

The rest of what you note above is trivial from that dataset.